# Automating GCE Shut down using Shell Script & Gloud SDK

Tags: linux, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to trying to execute a script using corn job, the script runs as required when i run it manually at the terminal but fails when i run it through a cron job. How can i make it run via cron?

Error: `gcloud: command not found`

```
#!/bin/bash

GCE_STATUS=$(gcloud compute instances list | awk '/my-gce-instance/' | awk '{print $NF}')
REQ_STATUS="TERMINATED"


if [[ $GCE_STATUS != $REQ_STATUS ]]; 
then
    echo "Google Compute Engine is currently Running - Shutting Down the Instance"
    gcloud compute instances stop my-gce-instance --zone=us-central1-a
else
    echo "Google Compute Engine is Already TERMINATED!!"
fi
```

Comment: Looks like you figured out how to do it, however, this is now a built-in feature of GCE: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following without making any changes to the cron job

```
GCLOUD="/Users/user-name/google-cloud-sdk/bin"
GCE_STATUS=$(${GCLOUD}/gcloud compute instances list | awk '/nc-de-docker-v3/' | awk '{print $NF}')
```